# Segmentation fault when using TF_SessionRun to run TensorFlow graph in C (not C++)

Tags: c, tensorflow

I'm trying to load and run a TensorFlow graph using the C API (I need to build outside of the TensorFlow project, and preferably without Bazel, so can't use C++).

The graph is a 3-layer LSTM-RNN which classifies feature vectors of 3 elements into one of 9 classes. The graph is built and trained in Python, and I've tested it in both Python and C++.

So far, I've got the graph loading, however I'm having trouble running the session once the graph is loaded. I've done a fair bit of digging around, but I've only found one example using the C API ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688217/how-to-load-a-graph-with-tensorflow-so-and-c-api-h-in-c-language)), and that doesn't include running the graph.

I've managed to put together the following, but it produces a segmentation fault (I can successfully run the code if I comment out the TF_SessionRun() call, but I get the seg fault when TF_SessionRun() is included). Here's the code:

```
#include "tensorflow/c/c_api.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>


TF_Buffer* read_file(const char* file);

void free_buffer(void* data, size_t length) {
        free(data);
}

static void Deallocator(void* data, size_t length, void* arg) {
        free(data);
}

int main() {
  // Use read_file to get graph_def as TF_Buffer*
  TF_Buffer* graph_def = read_file("tensorflow_model/constant_graph_weights.pb");
  TF_Graph* graph = TF_NewGraph();

  // Import graph_def into graph
  TF_Status* status = TF_NewStatus();
  TF_ImportGraphDefOptions* graph_opts = TF_NewImportGraphDefOptions();
  TF_GraphImportGraphDef(graph, graph_def, graph_opts, status);
  if (TF_GetCode(status) != TF_OK) {
          fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Unable to import graph %s", TF_Message(status));
          return 1;
  }
  else {
          fprintf(stdout, "Successfully imported graph\n");
  }

  // Configure input & provide dummy values
  const int num_bytes = 3 * sizeof(float);
  const int num_bytes_out = 9 * sizeof(int);
  int64_t dims[] = {3};
  int64_t out_dims[] = {9};

  float values[3] = {-1.04585315e+03,   1.25702492e+02,   1.11165466e+02};


  // Setup graph inputs
  std::vector<TF_Tensor*> input_values;
  TF_Operation* input_op = TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, "lstm_1_input");
  TF_Output inputs = {input_op, 0};
  TF_Tensor* input = TF_NewTensor(TF_FLOAT, dims, 1, &values, num_bytes, &Deallocator, 0);
  input_values.push_back(input);

  // Setup graph outputs
  TF_Operation* output_op = TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, "output_node0");
  TF_Output outputs = {output_op, 0};
  std::vector<TF_Tensor*> output_values(9, nullptr);

  // Run graph
  fprintf(stdout, "Running session...\n");
  TF_SessionOptions* sess_opts = TF_NewSessionOptions();
  TF_Session* session = TF_NewSession(graph, sess_opts, status);
  assert(TF_GetCode(status) == TF_OK);
  TF_SessionRun(session, nullptr,
                &inputs, &input_values[0], 3,
                &outputs, &output_values[0], 9,
                nullptr, 0, nullptr, status);

  fprintf(stdout, "Successfully run session\n");

  TF_CloseSession(session, status);
  TF_DeleteSession(session, status);
  TF_DeleteSessionOptions(sess_opts);
  TF_DeleteImportGraphDefOptions(graph_opts);
  TF_DeleteGraph(graph);
  TF_DeleteStatus(status);
  return 0;
}

TF_Buffer* read_file(const char* file) {
  FILE *f = fopen(file, "rb");
  fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
  long fsize = ftell(f);
  fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

  void* data = malloc(fsize);
  fread(data, fsize, 1, f);
  fclose(f);

  TF_Buffer* buf = TF_NewBuffer();
  buf->data = data;
  buf->length = fsize;
  buf->data_deallocator = free_buffer;
  return buf;
}
```

I'm not sure exactly where I'm going wrong with TF_SessionRun, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:** I've set a break point at the TF_SessionRun call in gdb, and as I step through it, I first get: 
`Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000100097650 in ?? ()`
followed by:
`"Cannot find bounds of current function"`
I initially thought this was as the TensorFlow library wasn't compiled with debug symbols, but have since compiled it with debug symbols and get the same output in gdb.

Since my original post I found a TensorFlow C example [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8033) (however the author points out that it's untested). As such, I've since re-written my code according to their example, and have double checked everything with TensorFlow's c_api.h header file. I'm also now calling the C API from a C++ file (as that's what's done in the above example). Despite all this, I'm still getting the same output from gdb.

**Update 2:** To ensure that my graph is loading properly, I've used some of the TF_Operation functions in the C API (TF_GraphNextOperation() and TF_OperationName()) to check the graph operations, and have compared these with the operations when loading the graph in Python. The output looks correct, and I can retrieve properties from the operations (e.g. using TF_OperationNumOutputs()), so it appears the graph is definitely loading correctly.

Advice from someone with experience using TensorFlow's C API would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Time for the debugger.

Comment: Do you know how to create a `core` dump file and how to use `gdb`?

Comment: Compile with warning and error flags will help you. Then use gdb and valgrind to understand your issue

Comment: Thanks, I've recompiled TensorFlow and the above code with debug symbols, and unfortunately this hasn't shed any more light on the situation. I've updated the post with details.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue after more time trying out functions in the C api and paying close attention to the dimensionality of my placeholders. My original seg fault was caused by passing the wrong operation name string to `TF_GraphOperationByName()`, however the seg fault only occurred at `TF_SeesionRun()` as this was the first place it tried to access that operation. Here's how I resolved the issue, for anyone facing the same problem:

Firstly, check your operations to ensure that they're assigned correctly. in my case, the operation name I provided to `input_op` was incorrect due to an error when obtaining the operation names in Python. The incorrect op name I got from Python was 'lstm_4_input'. I found this was incorrect by running the following on the loaded graph with the C API:

```
  n_ops = 700
  for (int i=0; i<n_ops; i++)
  {
    size_t pos = i;
    std::cout << "Input: " << TF_OperationName(TF_GraphNextOperation(graph, &pos)) << "\n";
  }
```

Where `n_ops` is the number of operations in your graph. This will print out your operation names; in this case I could see there was no 'lstm_4_input', but there was an 'lstm_1_input', so I changed the value accordingly. Furthermore, it validated that my output operation, 'output_node0', was correct.

There were a few other issues that became clear once I resolved the seg fault, so here's the complete working code, with detailed comments, for anyone facing similar problems:

```
#include "tensorflow/c/c_api.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>


TF_Buffer* read_file(const char* file);

void free_buffer(void* data, size_t length) {
        free(data);
}

static void Deallocator(void* data, size_t length, void* arg) {
        free(data);
        // *reinterpret_cast<bool*>(arg) = true;
}

int main() {
  // Use read_file to get graph_def as TF_Buffer*
  TF_Buffer* graph_def = read_file("tensorflow_model/constant_graph_weights.pb");
  TF_Graph* graph = TF_NewGraph();

  // Import graph_def into graph
  TF_Status* status = TF_NewStatus();
  TF_ImportGraphDefOptions* graph_opts = TF_NewImportGraphDefOptions();
  TF_GraphImportGraphDef(graph, graph_def, graph_opts, status);
  if (TF_GetCode(status) != TF_OK) {
          fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Unable to import graph %s", TF_Message(status));
          return 1;
  }
  else {
          fprintf(stdout, "Successfully imported graph\n");
  }

  // Create variables to store the size of the input and output variables
  const int num_bytes_in = 3 * sizeof(float);
  const int num_bytes_out = 9 * sizeof(float);

  // Set input dimensions - this should match the dimensionality of the input in
  // the loaded graph, in this case it's three dimensional.
  int64_t in_dims[] = {1, 1, 3};
  int64_t out_dims[] = {1, 9};

  // ######################
  // Set up graph inputs
  // ######################

  // Create a variable containing your values, in this case the input is a
  // 3-dimensional float
  float values[3] = {-1.04585315e+03,   1.25702492e+02,   1.11165466e+02};

  // Create vectors to store graph input operations and input tensors
  std::vector<TF_Output> inputs;
  std::vector<TF_Tensor*> input_values;

  // Pass the graph and a string name of your input operation
  // (make sure the operation name is correct)
  TF_Operation* input_op = TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, "lstm_1_input");
  TF_Output input_opout = {input_op, 0};
  inputs.push_back(input_opout);

  // Create the input tensor using the dimension (in_dims) and size (num_bytes_in)
  // variables created earlier
  TF_Tensor* input = TF_NewTensor(TF_FLOAT, in_dims, 3, values, num_bytes_in, &Deallocator, 0);
  input_values.push_back(input);

  // Optionally, you can check that your input_op and input tensors are correct
  // by using some of the functions provided by the C API.
  std::cout << "Input op info: " << TF_OperationNumOutputs(input_op) << "\n";
  std::cout << "Input data info: " << TF_Dim(input, 0) << "\n";

  // ######################
  // Set up graph outputs (similar to setting up graph inputs)
  // ######################

  // Create vector to store graph output operations
  std::vector<TF_Output> outputs;
  TF_Operation* output_op = TF_GraphOperationByName(graph, "output_node0");
  TF_Output output_opout = {output_op, 0};
  outputs.push_back(output_opout);

  // Create TF_Tensor* vector
  std::vector<TF_Tensor*> output_values(outputs.size(), nullptr);

  // Similar to creating the input tensor, however here we don't yet have the
  // output values, so we use TF_AllocateTensor()
  TF_Tensor* output_value = TF_AllocateTensor(TF_FLOAT, out_dims, 2, num_bytes_out);
  output_values.push_back(output_value);

  // As with inputs, check the values for the output operation and output tensor
  std::cout << "Output: " << TF_OperationName(output_op) << "\n";
  std::cout << "Output info: " << TF_Dim(output_value, 0) << "\n";

  // ######################
  // Run graph
  // ######################
  fprintf(stdout, "Running session...\n");
  TF_SessionOptions* sess_opts = TF_NewSessionOptions();
  TF_Session* session = TF_NewSession(graph, sess_opts, status);
  assert(TF_GetCode(status) == TF_OK);

  // Call TF_SessionRun
  TF_SessionRun(session, nullptr,
                &inputs[0], &input_values[0], inputs.size(),
                &outputs[0], &output_values[0], outputs.size(),
                nullptr, 0, nullptr, status);

  // Assign the values from the output tensor to a variable and iterate over them
  float* out_vals = static_cast<float*>(TF_TensorData(output_values[0]));
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
  {
      std::cout << "Output values info: " << *out_vals++ << "\n";
  }

  fprintf(stdout, "Successfully run session\n");

  // Delete variables
  TF_CloseSession(session, status);
  TF_DeleteSession(session, status);
  TF_DeleteSessionOptions(sess_opts);
  TF_DeleteImportGraphDefOptions(graph_opts);
  TF_DeleteGraph(graph);
  TF_DeleteStatus(status);
  return 0;
}

TF_Buffer* read_file(const char* file) {
  FILE *f = fopen(file, "rb");
  fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
  long fsize = ftell(f);
  fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);  //same as rewind(f);

  void* data = malloc(fsize);
  fread(data, fsize, 1, f);
  fclose(f);

  TF_Buffer* buf = TF_NewBuffer();
  buf->data = data;
  buf->length = fsize;
  buf->data_deallocator = free_buffer;
  return buf;
}
```

*Note:* in my earlier attempt, I used '3' and '9' as the `ninputs` and `noutputs` arguments for `TF_SessionRun()`, thinking that these related to the length of my input and output tensors (I'm classifying 3-dimensional features into one of 9 classes). In fact, these are simple the number of input/output tensors, as the dimensionality of the tensors is handled earlier when they're instantiated. It's easy to just use the .size() member function here (when using `std::vector`s to hold the `TF_Output`s).

Hopefully this makes sense and helps to clarify the process for anyone who finds themselves in a similar position in future!

Comment: Hi. If you're still on SO... can you remember why you added an extra output_value via TF_AllocateTensor? You already resized the output_values vector on creation, but then had to add an extra one? I'm also struggling with this lib. My output vector of TF_Tensor* is being written to, but they all seem to be empty.

Comment: Hi, so it's been quite a while since I've worked with the TF C API, it's possible things have changed. If I'm interpreting your question correctly (and if I remember correctly) the output_values vector holds the output_value tensor, which needs to be explicitly created using TF_AllocateTensor(), so just specifying the output_values vector isn't sufficient - I think I tried this and it resulted in an error, I don't recall having empty output tensors though (although, as I said, it's been a while).

Answer (score 0):

You can execute your code with gdb with this syntax:

```
gdb executable_name
```

Like this your process will run in gdb so you can get the backtrace after it crashes. After the crash you will have a console inside gdb so you can use the command bt to see the backtrace. Hopefully that should give you enough information to debug the issue. If not, you could also add your backtrace to your original post so people can see it.
Might be a good idea to read up on break points in gdb.

Comment: Thanks, I've recompiled TensorFlow and the above code with debug symbols, and run it in gdb with a breakpoint at the call to TF_SessionRun(). Unfortunately this hasn't shed any more light on the situation - I've updated the post with details.