# Exporting a Tensorflow network with Python and importing in C++ without Bazel

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

Using TensorFlow, I'm trying to load a network in a C++ file, that I trained in Python. I'm saving a network with input tensor `x` and output tensor `y` on Python with:

```
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
        tf.saved_model.simple_save(sess, export_dir, inputs={"ob": x}, outputs={"out": y})
```

Then, following these [examples](https://github.com/Neargye/hello_tf_c_api/blob/master/src/load_graph.cpp), I'm doing this in my C file:

```
TF_Buffer* buffer = ReadBufferFromFile("graph.pb");
TF_Graph* graph = TF_NewGraph();
TF_Status* status = TF_NewStatus();
TF_ImportGraphDefOptions* opts = TF_NewImportGraphDefOptions();

TF_GraphImportGraphDef(graph, buffer, opts, status);
```

But I'm getting a `TF_Status` error code `TF_INVALID_ARGUMENT` when doing the `TF_GraphImportGraphDef` call. The buffer is being loaded, I can print its length and get a value (192 in this case).

What should I do, or how can I do this? Using Bazel and the C++ API is not an option.

Comment: Has this been tried in tensorflow 2.0?

Comment: @jregalad Nope, it has not

Comment: I get it to work with TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel and model can be trained saving weights to a checkpoint file. But I just can;t get to reload said checkpoints into python again. It's driving me mad https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57993832/load-weights-from-checkpoint-not-working-in-keras-model